# Could my refilled printer cartridge be the cause of my misaligned printing?

Tags: printer, cartridge, canon-pixma

For the first time, instead of using a genuine cartridge, I bought a refilled one on eBay.

And, for the first time, the colour output is badly misaligned and results in blurred output.

If I print in greyscale all is well.

I've tried to align things, to no avail.

Thing is, I can't quite get my head around the cartridge itself and not the printhead being responsible.

Is it possible that if I replace the colour cartridge with a nice new one, my problems will disappear?

Comment: It's certainly possible. I only use and only recommend genuine ink and toner cartridges. There are others, of course, who swear by aftermarket and refilled cartridges.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove and reinsert the cartridge to be sure it is seated properly? I would ask for a refund and but a new one if it will not align properly

.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with some refilled cartridges is the connectors where the ink comes out is only rated for a certain amount of use, and when the cartridge is depleted, those connectors can either become partially or totally blocked.  A certified ink "refiller" should clean the connectors but even that won't fix it (being they're on eBay they might just be injecting new ink into an old cartridge and calling it a day).

I'd replace for a new cartridge, and try to clean the printer connectors as best as you can before reinserting a new cartridge.

(I'm also assuming your printer has ink cartridges and printheads...if it doesn't, then the printhead is on the cartridge and that tends to get "gunked" up as well.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but the existing answers are surprising and a correct answer should be available for future readers.

If the question was about a printer that uses cartridges that contain the printhead, it is conceivable that a third-party cartridge might be manufactured incorrectly, like the nozzles not being in precisely the right place.  The question is about a refilled cartridge, so even that possibility is pretty remote.

However, the question is about a printer for which the cartridges are just ink tanks that feed a printhead that is not disturbed (neither the nozzles nor the contacts are affected by cartridge replacement).  In this case, cartridge replacement has no effect on alignment, either causing problems or fixing them.